# Is there a way to identify the OpenGL context I am operating on?

Tags: opengl

When abstracting my game-/render-engine I hit the issue that I need a way to know reliably what context I am operating on.

I am looking for a solution that works within the OpenGL specification. That is standard OpenGL, nothing provided by *wrapper library xyz*.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. You created the OpenGL context. So how do you not know which context it is? Or do you have multiple contexts, and are trying to find out which is current?

Comment: @NicolBolas I am mostly playing around with a new toy I guess? The situation I have is that I am separating render-/opengl-code from the actual windows so I can shove my 'view'-objects between windows (which are more or less synonymous with contexts). I am having a field-day with shaders and programobjects and am currently at a point where I need a way to properly manage a mapping between object-ids and the context that id belongs to - I could & can identify context by providing some external means, but I am still curious what is available within the OpenGL spec.

Comment: @NicolBolas also I have stumbled upon glGetPointer and the beautiful [glDebugMessageCallback](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDebugMessageCallback.xhtml) which would allow me to abuse the latters user-pointer from OpenGL 4.3 upwards. I am currently doing some more digging/reading into that to see if that method's robust or not :)

Comment: With one context per thread, maybe you could query the thread you're on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I couldn't find anything for the OpenGL 3.3 Core Profile (most common version iirc), there's something available from version 4.3 onwards.

One can set a custom userpointer with [glDebugMessageCallback](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDebugMessageCallback.xhtml) and can retrieve that userpointer with [glGetPointerv](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetPointerv.xhtml).

Thus one could abuse the userpointer to mark a context.

Answer (score 2):

> I am looking for a solution that works within the OpenGL specification

Nope, gotta step up a layer and ask the OS's window system binding via `wglGetCurrentContext()`/`glXGetCurrentContext()`/`aglGetCurrentContext()`/etc.

Answer (score 1):

**Short:** No, there's no way to do this "within the OpenGL specification"

OpenGL specification doesn't care about HOW the context is created and managed.
The operating system and/or platform is responsible for this.

**Long:** If you control the application, then you should be able to detect when you are switching the OpenGL context. But if this is not the way you want to use, there's no other way... unless you setup different contexts with different settings (like the OpenGL version) or if they are running in separated threads. Again, this second one is not "OpenGL specification"... just tricks...